# api depends doesnt work with widget='mail_thread'

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo-10

I have this problem,I have a field that filter the messages when you click on Send message on the social network, but my problem is that i have to refresh the page to get the data. I wanna get it at the same time I send the message.

```
 @api.multi
 @api.depends('message_ids')
 def _compute_defect_summary_attachment_ids(self):
    body = ' '
    attachments = []
    cont = 1
    for rec in self:
        for msj in rec.message_ids:
            if msj.message_type == 'comment' and msj.subtype_id.name == 'Debates':
                soup = BeautifulSoup(msj.body)
                body += u'- Observación ' + str(cont) + ': ' + soup.text + '\n' \
                        + '- Reportante: ' + msj.create_uid.name + '\n' \
                        + '- Fecha: ' + msj.date + '\n\n'
                cont += 1
        rec.update({
            'defect_summary': body})
```

Trying fixing it, I saw when I add the widget doesn't work. Any idea? I need to use the also the widget.

Answer (score 1):

odoo 10 : Inherit mail.thread object in your class  and also you can add message_ids in view.you can use in any module or class.

1) models/custom.py

```
 class CustomDetails(models.Model):
     _name = 'custom.details'
     _inherit = ['mail.thread', 'ir.needaction_mixin']
```

2) views/custom_view.xml

```
<field name="message_ids" widget="mail_thread"/>
```